# For a given function f, is it possible to find the value of x where f(x) is minimum (Python)?

Tags: python, min

I have defined the following function using `lambda`:

```
f = lambda x: x**2 + 3*x + 3
```

Is there any way that I use `Python` to find the value of `x` that minimizes the value `f(x)`?

I know that `min()` function is to find the minimum element in a list of values, but here, I am not given the list of values, rather I need to locate the value of `x` that minimizes `f(x)`.

Thank you,

Comment: The fact that you've used a lambda expression is *completely* irrelevant.

Comment: In Python built-ins, almost certainly not; there's nothing with the level of intelligence to solve quadratic equations.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
You need to program the logic you'd use if you were doing this on paper.  Since you have not attempted a solution or researched an algorithm, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It's at x = -1.5. No need for Python, I did that in my head.

Comment: 1) derive the function: `f'(x) = 2*x + 3`, 2) study the sign of f', 3) when f' is equal to 0 in this case you have a min: x=-3/2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _"Is there any way to ..."_ should come with your research to find a way. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) Please also take the [tour], read [ask], provide a [mre], and ask a _specific_ question after you have made an attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @superbrain nope. for x = 0, y = 3/4. PS. I love how superb rain becomes super brain when tagging. nice one.

Comment: @superbrain err, sorry, rushed typing. I meant to say for x = -1.5 (i.e. what you proposed as the solution). my bad.

Comment: @superbrain argh, you're right, I got mixed up along the way and instead of solving for the derivative I started solving for the equation :facepalm: sorry, late night brainfart moment :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're *trying* to do can be done using python's symbolic package.
There are many other ways, but I suspect this will be the most useful to you.

```
>>> import sympy
>>> y = sympy.sympify("x**2 + 3*x + 3")
>>> sympy.solve( sympy.diff(y) )   # minimize by solving for the derivative
[-3/2]
```

Comment: @superbrain you're absolutely right. I meant to solve for the derivative. duh. Thanks for catching that!